# Criar arquivo de texto e fazer download sem armazena-lo no servidor

Tags: php

Como posso criar um arquivo no tempo de execução do script para fazer download dele, mas sem precisar salvar no diretório do servidor?

Algo como:

```
$dataOutput = "5s6a56sa565sa65a6s56sa565sa656sa565sa656as56sa556as5as";

//download
header('Content-Description: File Transfer'); ...
echo $dataOutput;
```

Comment: Só uma curiosidade, para que serve isso?

Comment: Quando eu preciso gerar um arquivo csv ou planilha com os dados do banco de dados

Answer (score 2):

PHP

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $content = $_POST['meuTextarea'].PHP_EOL;

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    // Indica o nome do arquivo como será "baixado". Você pode modificar e colocar qualquer nome de arquivo     
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=arquivo.txt');
    //header('Content-Length: '.strlen($content));
    //header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    //header('Expires: 0');
    //header('Pragma: public');
    echo $content;
    exit;
}
```

HTML  para criar conteúdo

```
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea name="meuTextarea">5s6a56sa565sa65a6s56sa565sa656sa565sa656as56sa556as5as</textarea>
<p><input type="submit" value="Gerar/enviar"></p>
</form>
```